# sSMTP From Address

Tags: linux, ssmtp

Is there a way to configure sSMTP to use a different name when sending emails?

I dont want my emails to my linux account as the username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the `man` pages of `ssmtp`

> REVERSE ALIASES
>          A reverse alias gives the From: address placed on a user's outgoing messages and (optionally) the mailhub these messages will be sent through. Example:
>
> root:jdoe@isp.com:mail.isp.com
>
> Messages root sends will be identified as from jdoe@isp.com and sent through mail.isp.com.
>
> FILES
>           /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf - configuration file
>           **/etc/ssmtp/revaliases** - reverse aliases file

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SMTP server you are using it may support the use of the `/etc/email-addresses`.  This is a way to provide aliases for sending addresses.  The standard configuration for `exim4` includes this functionality.

This can often be accomplished by your MUA (Mail User Agent).  Thuderbird allows you do configure a different source address than the user id used to connect.

Make sure your server is allowed to use you chosen address or your email may be classified as spam.  Using an authenticated connection to relay your email via the domain of your address should help in this case.